# Topology - Compactness of $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A question from my h.w.:

> Is the topological space $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0,1\}$
>     (where $\mathbb{Z}$
>     has the discrete topology and $\{0,1\}$
>     the trivial one) compact? sequentially compact? or compact at accumulation points?

I'm not sure I understand the construction, but I don't see how this space has any notion of compactness - the open covering $\{z\}\times\{0,1\}_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}$
 doesn't have a finite sub covering, same goes for the sequence $\{z\times\{0\}\}_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}$
 that doesn't have a limit or an accumulation point. Did I misunderstand something?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds right. What do you mean by the last question though: accumulation points of what? Those are something you talk about when given a subset of your space (and since the topology on the $\{0,1\}$-part is trivial, some sets have funky accumulation points).

Comment: Thanks!. An accumulation point $x$ of a set $A$ is a point belonging to to the closure of $A\setminus\{x\}$. What do you mean by funky? Compactness at accumulation points means every infinite subset has an accumulation point.

Comment: On second thought I think you're right - This space is in fact compact at accumulation points, as every element of the form $z\times0$ or $z\times1$ has as its closure the set $z\times\{0,1\}$. So given an infinite set including one such element, the other will always be an accumulation point of the set. Thanks!!

Comment: Yep (wasn't aware of your definition though; not sure that's completely standard? Might just be me though.) Those are exactly the "funky" ones I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already got the answer but adding my point of view won't do any harm :)

Denote $X=\mathbb{Z}\times\{0,1\}$.

- The space X is **not** compact: as you noticed $\{z\}\times \{0,1\}$ does not have a finite subcover.
- The space X is **not** sequentially compact: consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, $a_n=(n,1)$.

  No subsequence of $a_n$ converges $x_0\in X$, for if such $(a_{n_j})_{j=1}^\infty$ exists with $lim_{j\to\infty}a_{n_j}=x_0$,

  any open neighbourhood of $x_0$ (denoted $U$) has elements of the tail $(a_{n_j})_{j=l}^\infty$ in it, for any $l\in \mathbb{N}$.

  In other words: $\forall l\in\mathbb{N},\forall U_{x_0}: U_{x_0}\cap\{a_{n_j}|j>l\}\neq\phi$.

  But looking at $U_{x_0}=\{z\}\times\{0,1\}$ (where z is the first coordinate of $x_0$) and $l=z+1$ give the contradiction, hence X is not sequentially compact.
- The space X **is** limit point compact: Let look at a more common definition of limit point compactness: *X is said to be limit point compact if every infinite subset of X has a limit point in X, i.e a point x for which every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point of X different from x itself*.

  Let $S\subset X$ be an infinite set.
  $i,j\in\{0,1\}$ and $i\neq j$.
  Let $y=(k,i)\in S$ then any open neighbourhood of $x=(k,j)$ (even the smallest one $\{k\}\times \{0,1\}$) contains $y\in S$.

Comment: it is only now I notice it was asked 3 years ago :) oh well...

Comment: It is not much of a problem. Answering old questions without any answers is fine (as long as the question itself is remotely interesting). However, when you are only putting down what is already in the comments (which are not yours), it is customary to post the answer as community wiki.

Comment: How it is not sequentially compact?@Daniel

Comment: Talking about the first example? think of the limit of the sequence $a_n = (n,1)$ if such exists (some point of infinity, denote by $(\infty, 1)$ it certainly does not a part of the space X, hence the space does not follow the condition of sequential compactness. it has a sequence which converges to a limit that is not contained by the space, like any of its subsequences.